# Deadlock when creating WPF window in a thread

Tags: c#, wpf, deadlock, .net-4.8

I am creating a new window in a thread in .Net Framework 4.8 WPF application.
Most of time it works. However sometimes it hangs even when the app starts.
The dispatcher in the main thread and the dispatcher in the new thread wait each other.

You can refer to the following window to check threads.

[image: Threads window]

The following is the entire .cs code to reproduce the phenomenon. 'NewWindow' is a class derived from 'System.Windows.Window' and it does not have to have anything in it to reproduce the phenomenon(For clarification I also put code for 'NewWindow' at the end of this question).

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Interop;

namespace WindowCreateTest
{
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    NewWindow newWindow = null;
    Thread uiThread = null;
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void ShowNewWindow(IntPtr handle)
    {
      uiThread = new Thread(() =>
      {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "ShowNewWindow Thread";

        if (newWindow == null)
          newWindow = new NewWindow();

        WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(newWindow);
        helper.Owner = handle;

        newWindow.Show();

        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
      });

      uiThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
      uiThread.Start();
    }
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      var h = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
      ShowNewWindow(h);
    }
  }
}
```

You might wonder why I'm creating a new window in a newly created thread not in a main thread. The reason is that, this code is used in MAF(Managed Add-ins and Extensibility Framework or System.AddIn) dlls which is activated in an external process.

```
WindowInteropHelper helper = new WindowInteropHelper(newWindow);
helper.Owner = handle;
```

The reason I put the above two lines is

1. to make 'NewWindow' minimized when I minimize  'MainWindow'
2. to make 'NewWindow' always be placed over 'MainWindow'.

And I guess this is the root cause of the deadlock.

```
using System.Windows;

namespace WindowCreateTest
{
  public partial class NewWindow : Window
  {
    public NewWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you for reading and any advice will be welcomed and appreciated.

Comment: in `MainWindow` you set `uiThread = new Thread`, isn't the ui thead the current thread once the `MainWindow` created? At least by concept I think you shouldn't create uiThread like that. And If you want to create the UI thread from buttom up, i suggest you write a completely **console** application instead of wpf one.

Comment: What is the reason for creating a GUI in a child thread, STA or otherwise?  It will just lead to trouble.   I always thought MAF had its own built-in _sandboxing_

Comment: Again thank you for your comments. The reason for creating a GUI in a child thread is that, as I wrote in the question, the 'NewWindow' is created in an MAF dll. As @LeiYang said, actually the code for creating 'NewWindow' is called in 'AddInProcess.exe' which is almost like console application. 'AddInProcess.exe' is not what I made, but what .net framework creates.

Comment: have you ever learned how to start a wpf ui from console application? suggest you try the ways in book [Applications = Code + Markup](http://www.charlespetzold.com/wpf/)

Comment: @LeiYang, would you approach this issue in MAF(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/wpf-add-ins-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) aspects.  Actually I'm not in early phase of the development rather I'm at the very last point of the development process. I think I did not throughly review MAF before staring making my program two year ago.

Comment: @MickyD I assumed that I could open a window in MAF dll hosted in 'AddInProcess.exe' external process. If this problem cannot be solved easily, I must have made a big mistake two years ago.

Comment: are you using similiar implementaion as the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/how-to-create-an-add-in-that-is-a-ui?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

Comment: @LeiYang maybe you're right. I must have taken that 'How to: Create an Add-In That Is a UI' or 'How to: Create an Add-In That Returns a UI'.  As I wrote another comment, I assumed that I could open a window in MAF dll. I've come to far. I've written too much code already based on this  presumably wrong decision. It is best if I can get a workaround solution.

Comment: **if you're following the doc implementation**, can you create a minimal project(in github) to demonstrating the issue? i'd like to debug.

Comment: @LeiYang I really appreciate your suggestion. I must and will do anything if I can get any help. Before doing making a minimal demonstration project, I want to exactly understand your comment "if you're following the doc implementation"?

Comment: The MSDN link pointed to by Lei is very good.  It can be done _without additional threads_

Comment: @MickyD There is one more thing I need to consider. I'm creating MAF AddIn in a separate process to exploit full isolation. I want to make host alive even when MAF AddIn crashes. If I refer to the following link, I cannot 'just' take 'How to: Create an Add-In That Is a UI' or 'How to: Create an Add-In That Returns a UI' in a process level isolation.[link]( https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3c8592f2-14a6-418b-ab11-6d18096aaa0c/systemaddin-addinprocess-and-wpf?forum=wpf). By referring to the link, they suggest to "start a thread in the addin adaption layer'

Comment: @EthanKim _"...in a separate process to exploit full isolation. I want to make host alive even when MAF AddIn crashes."_ - please note MAF already does this: _[**Providing multiple application domain execution protection** .. provide a simple way to work around this problem and improve application stability.  You can detect all unhandled exceptions that occur in the application domain by handling the UnhandledException event of the WPF add-in's Dispatcher](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/app-development/wpf-add-ins-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#wpf-add-in-benefits)_

Comment: ....this was the BIG difference between MAF and MEF. :)  You could probably continue with a multiple process GUI approach but I think there are certain challenges with that approach even when MAF isn't involved.  Performance, marshalling, parenting a window from one process to another.  The latter can lead to thread deadlock

Comment: @MickyD Once again thank you for your comment. What I understand is that errors(I believe these are rather exceptions) from managed code can be well handled through application domain separation. But  I also want to protect the host from Add-In crash which results from unmanaged code or C dll calls inside the addin and I think that this can only be achieved through creating a different process. And about the deadlock, may I conclude, for now, that parenting a window from one process to another can lead to thread deadlock?

Comment: @EthanKim _"native code"_ - ah yes I understand now.  Yes tricky and I think your idea might be the way to go. :)